# Front page flooding due mass edits

Tags: discussion, editing, etiquette

Fitness.SE isn't as active as other sites where this problem might not be as recognizable as it is here.

Whenever mass edits are necessary, retagging for example, new questions get pushed off the front page.

Are there ways to mitigate this problem I might not know of? Is there a general guideline on how many edits in a row are OK? Bases on the mean activity level of fitness.SE the time frame of 'a row' seems to be rather long then.

Do we care at all? It might even be good to pull old, already answered questions to the front to get new users to participate in those, too, they maybe would have never searched for those. It makes the front page look more active and changing, though.

So, what do you think, how should we handle this?

Comment: Don't worry, 90% of our traffic comes on our site through Google and doesn't even see our regular front page

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I did not expect one. I actually didn't even know this got posted, I received an 'Oops!' while doing so :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry, 90% of our traffic comes on our site through Google and doesn't even see our regular front page

Also, when you click on the Questions page, you can sort for Newest, which shouldn't display all your edits.

So without going totally overboard, its OK to edit a large batch of questions, if they improve the quality of the site